# Master Detail Page with a Carousel Page - Text Alignment settings ignored when reopening

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an application which uses a Master Detail Page, one of the detail pages is a Carousel Page. I've discovered that the text alignment setting (at least for labels) is not adhered to in the event you navigate to a different page on the carousel, then a different detail page, then back to the carousel page, and back again to the first page being viewed on the carousel - here's a gif of the issue:

[image]

The first time you see my carousel page, it's Red and the text above it has some Aligned to the right, and some centered. The second time you see it, after navigating away. Both labels are aligned to the left.

This doesn't happen if the Carousel page with the labels on is the last one viewed prior to opening a new detail page (see the green page label is still centered in the gif).

Here's a link to it as a project if anyone's interested: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i9lrwra0ns2oyvq/MDP_Carousel_TextAlignBug.zip?dl=0

Is anyone aware of a way to force my carousel page to refresh with the labels properly aligned?

Comment: I haven't done this, but going forward it is recommended you use CarouselView and not CarouselPage. unfortunately it is still in prerelease in a separate NuGet package, it may not have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guys at Xamarin have got back to me and this has now been reported as an actual bug https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=53032

The fix for me has been to apply the Horizontal Options to the whole label rather than just the Text alignment.

```
myLabel.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End
```

From Xamarin: "There is still definitely an issue going on here, a combination of effects between how StackLayout, MasterDetail and CarouselView are interacting. Roughly, what I think is happening is that during the redraw of pages in the CarouselView not currently on screen, but in memory, are doing so inconsistently. I think HorizintalTextAlignment is being enforced on the text within the Label, but the actual Label control itself is only being drawn to the size of the text within the StackLayout instead of filling the horizontal space."